# open your app with http:// links in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

is there a way to open links like http://www.mydomain.app.com, so Safari would open it with my ios application? I managed to do it in android.

In ios i managed to open links with special scheme like somecheme:// using URL schemes in plist file.

But how to open http link with specific domain name? is it possible?

What i mean, is when you type or open some http url with www.domain.com/... the system suggests to open it using my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly – You want to open your app instead of the web page when the user follows a weblink on a certain domain, right? – here is a complete guide on how to do implement Universal Links on iOS 9:

http://blog.hokolinks.com/how-to-implement-apple-universal-links-on-ios-9/

Also check out the WWDC session: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-509/

Comment: Yes, this feature was introduced in iOS 9.0. So it works in 9.0 and newer versions only.

Comment: Yes, this was only implemented with iOS 9. The good thing is that on older iOS Versions, the link will still open in Safari, where you can point your users to download or open the app with a [smart app banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just like how you open other links in iOS app? Do you want to open it in external Safari browser or within your app. You can use SFSafariViewController or implement your own view controller using UIWebView or better WKWebView.

Note that in iOS 9 onwards you have to add the App Transport security settings dict in your Info.plist. Otherwise http sites will not open. You have to set Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES during development. For production you could choose to set this to know and then specify Exception Domains array if you are sure that you will open only certain websites.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste this

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.mydomain.app.com"]];
```

Comment: sorry, i changed the question. i asked it wrong the first time

Answer (score 0):

> so Safari would open it with my ios application? I managed to do it in android.

I think what you're asking is, how can I send out a link, like the one below, and when the user taps on it, it'll open my iOS application ?

If so, here's the solution:

[Custom URLs in iOS](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/XCode/CustomURLs.htm)

Basically, you need to make some changes to your .plist file to register your URL header:

[image]

When the user taps on such a URL, iOS will kick off your `openURL` function.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
```

Does this answer your question ?

Btw, the only thing I couldn't work out, was how to get my webpages to detect when a URL header *hadn't* been setup on an iOS device.

Eg, if my code hasn't registered "MKB", how can I get my webpage handle links like this one differently (perhaps redirecting them to the iTunes page, where they could install my app):

```
MKB://DocumentNumber=100
```

Comment: Ye, i did it in ios, but the scheme is not "http", it's some unique scheme

Comment: Exactly.  That tutorial page I quoted will show you how to register your own scheme, "MKB://..."  in this example.

Comment: no, i said that i know how to do it, it's not what i wanted

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open it on Safari, you can use

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:YOUR_NSURL_INSTANCE]];
```